# Is it valid to have the style on an element have an inherit value in the font family for when the font is missing?

Tags: html, css

If I have a page that this HTML

```
<body style="font-family:Helvetica">
    <span style="font-family:Segue">Hello World</span>
</body>
```

Is it valid to set the font family of the span to `Segue, inherit` to allow it to inherit the parent font if the first font listed is unavailable on the system?

```
<body style="font-family:Helvetica">
    <span style="font-family:Segue, inherit">Hello World</span>
</body>
```

It seems to work in the browser (Firefox) but Firefox's own debug tools are saying it's invalid.

In other words, is it OK to write `font-family: AnyFont, inherit`?

**Update:**
Using `inherit` does NOT work.

The question may now be, how to get a span to inherit the font when the font is not available.

Answer (score 3):

`inherit` exists on it's own. Adding `inherit` will inherit the parent font-family, whether it's own font-family exists or not (i.e the font-family you declared for span will be ignored even if it exists, it will just inherit the body's font-family).

You can simply do:

```
body {
   font-family: Helvetica;
}
span {
   font-family: Segue, Helvetica;
}
```

That way, it uses `Segue`, if it is not available it shifts to `Helvetica`.
So in your code, in the span style, declare the fonts you want it to fall back to, separated by commas.

Answer (score 1):

It's invalid. [`inherit` may only exist on its own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24473976/is-it-safe-to-use-inherit-in-css-font-family/24474022#24474022) in a property declaration.

While the entire declaration is in fact ignored, it appears to work because `font-family` is inherited by default anyway.

[Without using custom properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37442603/how-to-use-commas-in-a-css-variable-fallback), it's not possible for an element to fall back to its parent's font stack without respecifying the entire stack as fallbacks.

Comment: So what does it mean when it works as expect? In my tests, `Aria, Helvetic, inherit` works. As I correct the spelling, `Arial, inherit` etc each font is shown correctly. Can I use it or depend on it? I need to be able to have a Span fallback on it's parent font (all the way up to the body) if the specified font is missing. Without adding `,inherit` to the `font-family` value it only seems to inherit the browser default font of Times New Roman.

Comment: @1.21 gigawatts: Are you specifying a different font from the parent? font-family: Arial, inherit should not result in Arial if the parent is not in Arial and the font itself is installed on the machine.

Comment: After another test, `Segue,` is all that is needed for it to inherit the parent value. `Inherit` isn't even needed. It seems the comma invalids it and it looks up the chain. The Span has a font of Segue UI. The body has Arial. My earlier tests were flawed it does not work with inherit.

Comment: @1.21 gigawatts: The comma invalidates the declaration when it's not followed by anything. The inherit keyword invalidates the declaration when it's not the only token in the property value.

Comment: One question, honest answer. Do you think it would be useful if you could use `inherit` with other font values? As in, "font-family: font1, font2, inherit"?

Comment: @1.21 gigawatts: With a different keyword, probably.

Comment: You don't want to reuse `inherit`? What about something like `font-family: myFont1, myFont2, document` or something like a new style "`inherit-font-family-from-container-when-font-is-not-found: true`" of course using a more concise name? How about "`font-family: myFont1, myFont2, #elementID, .ClassName, :parent`" to fall back on the font of a class, id of an element or parent?

Comment: @1.21 gigawatts: It's not that the CSSWG "doesn't want" to reuse it so much as they don't want to redefine the grammar of the "inherit" keyword and potentially force browsers to alter their CSS parsers to accommodate the change. It's much easier to just use a unique keyword that can be tacked on to the existing font-family grammar.